# "Нарушение прав доступа при записи" в константную строку

Tags: c++, указатели

Здравствуйте! Возможно глупый вопрос, но не могу понять, почему компилятор ругается последнюю строку:

```
char *str;
char *b;
str="d       ";
b=strchr(str,0);
b--;
while( *b==' '){
    b--;
}
b++;
*b=0;
```

Comment: Как именно ругает? И какой компилятор?

Comment: В Visual studio выходит "нарушение прав доступа при записи"

Comment: Это сообщение компилятора или runtime'а? (И вообще, очень нравятся вопросы такого тип: "ругается", не приводя текст сообщения об ошибке).
Ну а причину @mikillskegg уже указал.

Comment: По стандарту такой код в С++ вообще не должен компилироваться.

Comment: извините, спасибо учту.
Не могли бы вы подробней объяснить почему при инициализации не указателем, а массивом не вышло ошибки?

Comment: Потому что массив в данном случае создается в стеке и инициализируется значением из присваиваемой строки. А стек может изменяться.

Comment: @mikillskegg Ссылочку на место в стандарте нельзя ли получить? (g++ даёт "предупреждение" на str="d ";)

@Никита в массив (локальный или глобальный) писать не воспрещается

Comment: @Никита Не "инициализация массивом", а инициализация массива значением строки. В этом случае str -- не указатель, а массив (хотя мог бы с таким же результатом быть указателем на (изменяемый) массив). А в первом варианте -- указатель на неизменяемую строку (константу), размещаемую в секции read-only.

Comment: А что должен делать этот код? Возвращать указатель на первый пробел после буквы внутри строки и заменять то на что он указывает нулем?

Comment: @igumnov, этот код часто называют trim() - удалить пробелы в конце строки.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял.
Нет, обрезает все пробелы в строке справа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка `*b=0;`  пытается изменить константную строку, которая находится в секции исполняемого файла, помеченной как read-only.

Comment: а не подскажите как это можно обойти,если мне нужно изменить эту строку?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

     char str[] = "d    ";

Comment: т.е. записать символ конца строки туда,куда указывает данный указатель